# Subclassing tf.Tensor for both Graph and Eager Execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I would like to subclass the `tf.Tensor` class. The idea is that the objects of subclasses should behave like Tensors (i.e. I can use them to make any kind of tf operations) but they should also possess others attributes which provide them specific behaviors inside my framework.

Up to now, I worked in Graph mode and I simply do something like this:

```
class EnrichedTensor(tf.Tensor):

    def __init__(self, tensor, other_stuff):
        super(EnrichedTensor, self).__init__((
                              op=tensor.op,
                              value_index=tensor.value_index,
                              dtype=tensor.dtype)
        self.other_stuff = other_stuff
```

Now, I would like to do the same to work only in eager mode, but I really don't know (and I didn't find anything) about `EagerTensor` instantiation. Obviously, the `op` attribute does not make sense anymore.

I tried to work on the *creation* of the object through the `__new__` method but I found problems in subclassing my `EnrichedTensor` and following the creation path.

So, I was wondering if is there any way to do this cleanly and in a "sound" way.